# CentOS running inside VMware as WebServer times out on outside connection

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, webserver

I have a CentOS machine running inside VMware. I have got PHP and Apache set up on it.

If I open a browser (on the VM) and go to either localhost or 192.168.0.3, I get a phpinfo page I made in `/var/www/html/index.php`. But on the host (Windows 7), in my browser I go to 192.168.0.3 and it times out.

I can ping the IP address from Windows 7 and get a response. I just can't it through a browser.

This is my first time using a VM and I'm getting lost in the network settings. Does anyone have any ideas what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you allowed the http port apache listens on to pass the firewall? CentOS usually installs with a quite tight iptables-policy.

Disable with: `service iptables stop`

If that did help, do `service iptables start` and enable the configured port. Should be something like: `iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -dport 80 -j ACCEPT` for input and `iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -sport 80 -j ACCEPT` for output.

Furthermore: are you sure networking is configuerd properly? Did you choose NAT? Bridging? A vmnet?

Comment: Cheers, iptables was the issue. Just a note no anybody else who has this issue, rather that `-dport` and -`sport` the comand for me was just -d and -s, and you have to do `service iptables save` once you've added the rules.